# What is the meaning of 'Züge' in this context?

Tags: translation, vocabulary

From Hesse's *Der Steppenwolf*:

> So etwa war mein Eindruck, und er wäre kein guter gewesen, wenn er nicht durch allerlei kleine Züge durchkreuzt und korrigiert worden wäre.

This sentence is referring to the narrator's impression of the 'Steppenwolf'.

Are the *Züge* in the sense of pen marks, which have '*durchkreuzt und korrigiert*' the narrator's written description of the man? If so, why would this have a negative effect on the way the *Steppenwolf* appears in this description (*'er wäre kein guter gewesen, wenn...'*)? Or is it something else entirely?

Comment: Better think of _chess_ or _game moves_.

Comment: Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: Well, _moves_ of the person in question (the _Steppenwolf_). Also possible meaning is _traits_ (of character).

Comment: I think "Züge" means in this context: im Sinn von "Wesenszug" (characteristic trait), "Verhaltensweisen" (behavior, manner) - like Steppenwolf acted in the past. And these makes the narrator change his mind about this man.

Answer (score 1):

An english [translation](http://www.kkoworld.com/kitablar/Herman_Hesse_Yalquzaq_eng.pdf) of the book offers this translation: "Such more or less was my impression, and it would certainly not have been a good one if it had not been revised and corrected by many small instances."

<s>I think that *Züge* in the German original can be interpreted as *moves* as in moves in a game of chess.</s>

Alternatively, after reading more context, I think it might also mean *Charakterzüge* (traits) as he is talking about a man and his impression of him.

Actually, I am now quite convinced that it is *Züge* as in *ziehen* (to pull), meaning small instances *pulling* on his opinion of this man, like small forces acting on an object. However, other translations seem to interpet it as "traits", maybe even as figurative pen strokes.

Comment: Aha, thank you, the meaning of it has just clicked.

Comment: I agree that it probably means "Spielzüge" as in Chess or similar games.

Comment: @JThistle Please check my latest edit. I think I was mistaken.

Comment: I think the translator used "instances" for "Züge" in the sense of "Gelegenheiten", as like as "several opportunities". As like as described in my comment above (sorry for repetition): im Sinn von "an den Tag gelegter Wesenszug" (shown characteristic traits in the past), "Verhaltensweisen" (behavior, manner) - like Steppenwolf acted in the past. And these makes the narrator change his mind about this man.